# mono_odometer of viso2_ros don't generate timestamp information

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I use gscam (http://www.ros.org/wiki/gscam) to generate a video stream and mono_odometer application of viso2_ros (http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros#) to process it and compute visual odometry.
Giving a look at the odometry  messages I get the following info:

```
aldo@aldo-ubuntu:~/Projects/4thRC/BergamoComponents/services_caller/bin$ rostopic echo /mono_odometer/odometry
header: 
  seq: 7
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: /odom
child_frame_id: /base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0358117049907
      y: -0.105056291215
      z: 1.05073866966
    orientation: 
      x: 9.03653364967e-05
      y: -0.000380259093953
      z: -0.000498042565549
      w: 0.999999799595
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 8
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: /odom
child_frame_id: /base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0409528148301
      y: -0.116839589994
      z: 1.17038278247
    orientation: 
      x: 0.000299344860283
      y: -0.000918266853756
      z: -0.000664260264014
      w: 0.999999312968
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

As you can see odometry info (position and orientation) are updated properly, but timestamp (secs and nsecs) are never updated.
I think rviz can't show me the robot odometry or position for that issue, but I'm not sure.
Can anybody help me? Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43636/mono_odometer-of-viso2_ros-don%27t-generate-timestamp-information/) by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2012-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [axp'dc](https://answers.ros.org/users/60966/axp%27dc/) on 2020-10-17**:
Hi there. I was wondering if you could explain how you got the odometry data to publish when running. I am trying to get images from a rosbag and i am using a launch file to remap topics. When I run rostopic echo /mono_odometer/odometry, nothing appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed it!
Use the patch described at :

http://toychest.in.tum.de/wiki/_media/fastdev:gscam.patch

in particularly, add the following instructions in src/gscam.cpp:

```
ros::Time now = ros::Time::now();
msg.header.stamp.sec = now.sec; 
msg.header.stamp.nsec = now.nsec;
camera_info.header.frame_id = frame_id;
camera_info.header.stamp.sec = now.sec; 
camera_info.header.stamp.nsec = now.nsec;
```

Bye

---

Originally posted by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) with karma: 252 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0